# Failing to Instantiating String Array Inside Switch Statement - Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, switch-statement, instantiation

For some reason the String[] champs isn't being instantiated and I can't seem to see why
Shouldn't  `champs = new String[]{ "BLAH", "BLAH", "BLAH"};` initialize the array?

```
  public static String[] getChamps() {

    String rolereturn = ChampSelect.getRoles();

    //Switch to Determine Champion Suggestions


    String[] champs; //String Declaration

    switch (rolereturn) {

        case "AD Carry": //AD Carry Selection Options
            champs = new String[]{ "Ashe", "Caityln", "Draven", "Ezreal", "Kog'Maw", "Sivir", "Twitch", "Varus", "Vayne" };
            break;

        case "AP Carry": //AP Carry Selection Options
            champs = new String[]{ "Diana", "Evelyn", "Kassadin", "Kennen" };
            break;

        case "Support": //Support Selection Options
            champs = new String[]{ "Janna", "Nunu", "Shen", "Soraka", "Taric", };
            break;

        case "AP Jungle": //AP Jungle Selection Options
            champs = new String[]{ "Diana", "Fiddlesticks" };
            break;

        case "AD Jungle": //AD Jungle Selection Options
            champs = new String[]{ "Kha'Zix", "Nocturne", "Rengar", "Udyr", "Warwick", };
            break;

        case "AP Top": //AP Top Selection Options
            champs = new String[]{ "Akali", "Cho'Gath", "Kennen", "Malphite", "Shen", "Singed", "Teemo" };
            break;

        case "AD Top": //AD Top Selection Options
            champs = new String[]{ "Fiora", "Irelia", "Jax", "Kha'Zix", "Master Yi", "Nasus", "Nidalee", "Rengar", "Zed" };
            break;
    }
    return champs;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run this method with the debugger to check if one of the case statements is executed? by the way: When you have a switch statement, you should always have a `default` case which does something meaningful or throws an exception.

Comment: Although yours SHOULD WORK, You may also remove this `[]` from `champs = new String[]`. Just try using `String[] champs = {"x", "y", "z"}....` +1 @Philipp

Comment: @bonCodigo if you do this inside each case the array wouldn't be accessible after the switch anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct it would initialise the array if one of the case statements were called. I would add a `default` in there and then throw if that `default` is called. The default is called when no case statement is matched. It looks like you are covering all case statements so have a `default` throw would be a good idea.

Something like this should do it

```
 default: throw new RuntimeException("SHould not be here " + rolereturn);
```

Comment: Thank you this was exactly it, I haven't used switch statements before and did not think to put a default in, now to finish the rest!

Comment: @SeanPatrickDill which is a good thing, nobody should use switch statements, ever, see my answer for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `Map` rather than a switch case,

```
public static String[] getChamps() {

    Map<String,String[]> map = new HashMap();
    map.put("AD Carry",new String[]{ "Ashe", "Caityln", "Draven", "Ezreal", "Kog'Maw", "Sivir", "Twitch", "Varus", "Vayne" });
    // ... and so on for all your cases

    String rolereturn = ChampSelect.getRoles();
    if (!map.containsKey(rolereturn)) throw new IllegalArgumentException(rolereturn);

    return map.get()    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is a problem with `rolereturns` not being what you think. Could you try and add a default at the end of your switch, set the array to something, and see if *that* does it?

Otherwise simply debug and check that you go into the right lines...